# RelativeLayout doesn't match parent's height

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

The relativelayout inside main layout won't fill the parent height when it's displayed on device. In fact i want the left-side layout with the yellow color to fill the row vertically.
[image]

here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/verses_relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.ad.holyquran.extra.TextViewEx
    android:id="@+id/textView_Verse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versesRelativeLayout"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/versesTextSize"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_VerseTranslation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Verse"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versesRelativeLayout"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text Text Text Text Text Text"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/versesRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#fff3f27f">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/verseNumberIcRL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/versesImageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/verse_number_ic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_verseNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/versesImageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="280"
            android:paddingBottom="28dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#ff000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I just tried your xml code and the layout fills the height.. Try removing the 2nd `RelativeLayout` ID = `verseNumberIcRL` I think it's unnecessary.. Why is your custom view `TextViewEx` set to `layout_marginTop="-15dp"`? That could be what is causing the problem.

Comment: that's because i have two more relative layouts similar to verseNumberIcRL. And the layout_marginTop="-15dp" is because after setting the font, the text would go 15dp down from where it is now.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the line

android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versesRelativeLayout"

It will stop being on the right. If you need the yellow as background, then in the main layout  (which is the first relativeLayout) set it as the background using 
android:background="@drawable\image"

You may need to put all the other elements inside the main RelativeLayout. 
Hope this helps.
    I couldn't see the end tag of the main RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the tag in layout versesRelativeLayout:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_VerseTranslation"

<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/versesRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#fff3f27f"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_VerseTranslation"
            >
```

Comment: That only aligned the layout to textview_VerseTranslation, the top part is empty again.